# Sort only array elements JavaScript which has a CSS property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to create an unordered list. The order should be given by their id (Which is a number. The smallest is at the bottom.)

BUT if a certain li does not have a a CSS property (text-decoration:line-through in my case.) Then they should be at the bottom anyway.

I am trying to make a To Do list, where checked elements are at the bottom, but when you uncheck them, they jump back to place.

http://codepen.io/balazsorban44/pen/Gjzwbp

```
const inputArea = document.getElementById('todo-input');
const list = document.getElementById('tasks');
tasks = [];
function loaded() {
    inputArea.focus();
}

function enter() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        addTask()
    }
}

function refresh(array) {
    var task = document.createElement('li');
    const checkBox = document.createElement('input');
    checkBox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    checkBox.setAttribute('onclick', 'toggleCheckBox()');
    task.appendChild(checkBox);
    task.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[array.length - 1].task));
    task.id = array[array.length - 1].timestamp.getTime()
    list.appendChild(task);
    return list;
}

function addTask() {
    if (inputArea.value != '') {
        tasks.push({
        timestamp: new Date(),
                task: inputArea.value
        });
        inputArea.value = '';
        inputArea.focus();
        refresh(tasks);
        doneOrUndone();
        inputArea.placeholder = 'Click + or press Enter.'
    } else {
        inputArea.placeholder = 'Write something'
    }
}

function doneOrUndone() {
    var done = 0
    const out = document.getElementById('out')
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].style.textDecoration != '') {
            done++
        }
    }
    out.value = parseInt(done) + '/' + parseInt(tasks.length) + ':'
}

function toggleCheckBox() {
    const task = event.target.parentNode
    if (task.style.textDecoration == '') {
        task.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        list.appendChild(task)
        doneOrUndone()
    } else {
        task.style.textDecoration = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            if (task.id < tasks[i].timestamp.getTime() && list.childNodes[0].style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
                if (task.id > list.childNodes[0].id) {
                list.insertBefore(task, list.childNodes[0]);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                list.insertBefore(task, list.childNodes[i]);
                    break
            }
        }
        doneOrUndone()
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code... explain which specific part isn't working correctly...

Comment: I just did! the part which is working incorrectly is the toggleCheckBox() function I think. There should the sorting happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem is that when setting `style.textDecoration` to `line-through`, the actual property that is set is `textDecorationLine`.

Your line `if (task.style.textDecoration == '')` is therefore always true.

You can replace `textDecoration` with `textDecorationLine` and it should work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwzzkP

---

The underlying cause of this problem is, in my opinion, that you're using an element's `style` attribute to monitor *state*. I'd advice to either:

1. Store state in javascript, or
2. Store state in a class, or
3. Store state in a custom `data-` attribute

For example:

```
const task = event.target.parentNode;
const isDone = task.getAttribute("data-done");
task.style.textDecoration = !isDone ? 'line-through' : '';
task.setAttribute("data-done", !isDone);
```

Comment: it only breaks my code if I use textDecorationLine. Setting it does no change on the page, and I also get an undefined error in console when I check the content of it on an element.